# Qr Code decoder

Tags: c++, qr-code

Is there any way to write a QR-code decoder in C++ from scratch? I have done that already in Python using `SimpleCv` module to access the webcam.

Thanks

Comment: Because I don't know if it's possible to have simple computer vision in C++

Comment: Before you can decode a QR code, you must first take a picture of one. It's not clear which of these two things your question is about. The QR decode is platform-independent, but interfacing with a camera is 100% platform-dependent, and you don't mention your platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) has a C++ detector and decoder. All you need to give it is the RGB or luminance image data as a vector.

(Full disclosure: I'm the primary maintainer of the ZXing C++ QR port at this point.)

Comment: Everybody is talking about ZXing, but There is no proper documentation about how to use it maybe you can send me a link for that or so?

Comment: Yeah, there's not a lot of documentation. I think most people read the sample apps and the source. They're fairly easy to read. Not ideal, but certainly easier than trying to develop a solution from scratch.

Comment: @smparkes I wanted to use QR Code Library for Windows Store App in C++.I want to generate QR Code based on Three Info WiFI SSID,WIFI Security and Password. Plz guide me how to it.I am not able to configure Zxing in my project

Comment: here is an example of using zxing in c++ code http://wiki.ssrrsummerschool.org/doku.php?id=robocup2012:qrcode-cppexample

Comment: Can you please tell what's current status of ZXing & CPP? I see two things.. 1. an older version `zxing/cpp`(there is a link in ZXing repo itself) & 2. another repo `glassechidna/zxing-cpp`. Can you please tell what would be a good option?

Comment: The version in the zxing repo has been retired. It was an initially-automated translation of the java that was then manually curated. It was removed when the maintainer (me, at the time) moved on. Reading the description of the second repo, it's based on the last C++ commit in the main repo that someone found useful ...

Comment: @smparkes I have checked your code, but it is so large. Would be great if you rebuild components in a modular architecture so , if I need to say... only scan for QR Code, I just copy few `.cpp ` classes and that's it. But you have 128 files in total, all these objects will create unneeded weight for a mobile app. Just giving you ideas for improvement.

Comment: @Nulik the C++ code in ZXing is deprecated and there's no work going on it at this point, I'm afraid.

Comment: @smparkes, hmmm, too bad. Thanks for the info. BTW, I am looking at ZBar right now, it seems that their C code can be easily adapted to scan QR code. If that is true, the only thing left to do will be to create QQuickItem that will read the camera and send the picture to ZBar

Answer (score 8):

I'm one of the core SimpleCV developers.  We used to support ZXing, but the problem was it was java based and quite slow running outside of it's own application.  As of last week I updated the code to support [Zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/).  It's c++ based, and is very fast and much easier to install and run.  They also have examples on how to run your own code and should work with OpenCV if you need much faster speeds.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Xamox, Everytyhing fine? with the GSoC Student? I gonna take a look at those example thanks you

Comment: Yeah, the GSoC students are doing some cool things. A mobile app for android should be out soon.  If you do want to use zbar, on ubuntu 12.04 you can install it with just 'sudo apt-get install python-zbar'

Comment: I have had problems getting ZBar running on macOS

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ZXing for Java, but on their website it says they have partial support for C++
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/